# Genexus X Ev 3 Assign data to Elements in Transaction

Tags: attributes, assign, genexus

I have some problems trying to assign values to my Transaction Attribute based on a Business Component (for a Foreign Key Transaction).

- If I want to assign then in the event, I get a `spc0150` error (`Cannot update database. Changes to database are only allowed in procedures`)
- If I put this in a Rule, I get a `spc0158` warning (`Rule 'OperacionChTasaInteres = &Analisis.Analisistasa IF &Cambioempresa .AND. .NOT. &Errorempresa ; ' not included.`) and the rule is not executed.

I have a lot of attributes to assign, so the last and dirty way I think is a Procedure call in the Rules that read (again) Transaction and return the values as outputparameters, but if I have to do this a lot of times and I have to create a lot of procedures, just for initialization and calculations.
After try this, I have the procedure, but because the condition variables are assigned on an event, the Rule is never executed.

The dirty option I think is to add all the needed Attributes of this Foreign Key Transaction into the Transaction I need his fields, but I'll finish with a long and dirty transaction.

Thanks a lot, Ariel

Comment: Could you explain the data model, the transaction's structure, and what is the rule that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you using the Business Component?
There are 3 ways to insert, update or delete data in GeneXus:

1. Object Transaction: where you not only can type data, you can change
   it in "Rules" (i.e.: Att1 = Att2 * Att3 if condition;), you can't do
   this in "events".
2. Procedures, using "For each" to update or delete,
   and "New" to insert.
3. Business component (not recommended, it blocks
   tables a lot): In a transaction you set "Business Component" = True,
   then you define a variable based in this transaction in a procedure
   or webpanel. You are not supposed to use Business component inside a
   transaction object.

Comment: Hi Sebastian. Thanks for your help. I'm in a Transaction, so I need to change the data en a Rule, but the data comes from a Foreign Key table, so I tryied to use Rule, but as I put in the question, the rules are not executed, then I tryied in a procedure in a rule as output parameters, but the procedure isn't executed too

Comment: I assume AnalisisTasa is an infered attribute and you have in the transaction an attribute AnalisiId(FK)
`*OperacionId
 OperacionChTasaInteres
 AnalisisId (FK)
 AnalisisTasa`

The rule should be: `OperacionChTasaInteres = AnalisisTasa if &CambioEmpresa and not &ErrorEmpresa and After(AnalisisId);`

Remember the "Not included" could be because the variables "&CambioEmpresa" and "&ErrorEmpresa" are not being set anywhere nor being received as parameter.

Comment: That you suggest is the last option, because I have a lot of fields, so I don't want to mess up my transaction with all the attributes I need for the calculation, thats why I tryied firls using a Business Component for the foreign key. There is another option to do this?

Comment: You could call a procedure that fill a SDT with all the fields you need to calculate.

Comment: Thanks again. The problem I have with that is that the condition variables are assignes in the IsValid event and the rule is never executed. Is there a way to say in the event to refresh the rules (remember I'm in a transaction so the refresh doesn't work)

Comment: You should managed it with rules, but if you really need to change attributes in events, you could "cheat". Example: you have attribute OperacionChTasaInteres and you want to asign it in the Att1.IsValid, you could call proc MyProc.call(OperacionChTasaInteres, Analisistasa)  (with Commit on exit = False) that recieves Parm(out:&OperacionChTasaInteres, in:&Analisistasa) and in source: &OperacionChTasaInteres = &Analisistasa. Buy I'm sure the problem is that you are trying to assign values that are not set. Try to give then values in the Start Event.

Answer (score 0):

If variables are set in the IsValid event, try to put your variables in the form. You can put them all in a table and hide it in the Start Event. If it doesn't work, add the rules Accept(&Variable1); Accept(&VariableX);
Remember you will hide them, so, no problem if they are editabled.

Comment: Thanks again. I've test what you say, but after assigning the value of the condition variables in the IsValid Event it refresh the values of the variables in the screen, but not triggers the rules (bbecause the Rules are executed before the event). The workarroud I use now is to trigger the rules without all the conditions, but I don't know if I'll be able to do this for all the situations

Comment: Did you used: OperacionChTasaInteres = &Analisistasa If &Cambioempresa and not &Errorempresa and after([Atribute yuo defined the IsValidEvent)? And what do you do in the IsValid? Can't you do it in the rules?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've checked that, but no.Iv've checked to to add a javascript that call the onchange and onblur for that field, but no